# Can PHP 5.3.15 be installed on Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04

I'm using a machine running Ubuntu 11.04 and PHP 5.3.5 to test an application that will run on a server with PHP 5.3.15.

I've noticed some differences and would prefer a test environment as similar as possible to the final home of the project, but all my searches for a way to update PHP to a specific version have come up empty.

Is there a way to replace 5.3.5 with 5.3.15 on this machine running Natty Narwhal?

Comment: Is the server that it will run on Ubuntu?  Ubuntu's php release can have different version numbers than the offical php release.  From what I can tell you should be at 5.3.10 on an updated Ubuntu server also.

Comment: The commercial server is running Red Hat 4.1.2-52

Comment: Would it not make more sense to run a Red Hat VM?  Then your test environment is the same as your production not just your php version.

Comment: I guess it does. Will have to dive into VM 101. Thanks

Comment: Try VirtualBox its really easy to get setup.  Plenty of guides online if you have problems.

Comment: Your biggest problem with what you're asking is that you presumably have no control over when or whether the live server will be updated. 5.3.15 is not the current version (currently at 5.3.24, and there are important security fixes between 15 and 24). The best option would be to make sure that both systems are fully up-to-date. You don't want a live system running an old version, so that needs to be updated to .24 as soon as possible. It then becomes easier keep your dev system at the latest rather than trying to force a specific version for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Zend Server CE](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/downloads). It's an extremely nice PHP application stack.

According to the docs for the [DEB installation](http://files-source.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-Community-Edition/zend-server-community-edition.htm#deb_installation.htm), you should be able to do something like

```
./install_zs.sh 5.3.15 ce
```

Please note I haven't tried setting the PHP version like this directly but it's worth a try.